# Consultar datos en php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Buenas, quiero mostrar todos los valores ingresados en la fecha de hoy en php. Pero, por algún motivo no me los muestra. Al día de hoy, hay un dato cargado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que, sino hay datos en el día de hoy, me muestre los del día anterior. Esto es lo que hago en PHP:

```
//consulta si hay datos hoy
    $sqlHoyNoNull = "SELECT z.nombreZona, cpp.precioMinimo, cpp.precioMaximo, (cpp.precioMinimo + cpp.precioMaximo)/2 AS promedio FROM cargaPrecioPapas cpp INNER JOIN zonas z ON cpp.fkZona = z.idZona 
    WHERE fechaCargaPrecio = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y')";
    //WHERE fechaCargaPrecio = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y') AND cpp.precioMinimo < 100 AND cpp.precioMaximo > 100";
    
    //consulta con datos de ayer
    $sqlAyer = "SELECT z.nombreZona, cpp.precioMinimo, cpp.precioMaximo, (cpp.precioMinimo + cpp.precioMaximo)/2 AS promedio FROM cargaPrecioPapas cpp INNER JOIN zonas z ON cpp.fkZona = z.idZona WHERE fechaCargaPrecio = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%d/%m/%Y')";
    
    $result1 = $conn->query($sqlHoyNoNull);
    $result2 = $conn->query($sqlAyer);
    
    if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row[] = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
            $tem = $row;
            $json = json_encode($tem);
        }
    }else{
        while($row[] = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            $tem = $row;
            $json = json_encode($tem);
        }
    }
 echo $json;
 $conn->close();
```

¿Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Y que no te muestra? el dia de hoy? tampoco te muestra el dia de ayer? que error te sale? que pasa si le haces un var_dump a los resultados?

Comment: Ademas has intentado hace la consulta con fechas estaticas?

Comment: Al realizar un var_dump de los resultados, obtienes algo ??

Comment: Ya me di cuenta que era un error mío, ya que a la hora de registrar una fecha en vez de almacenar el día como: 01 lo almacenaba como 1. Por lo que el error estaba en otra parte, mis disculpas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas queriendo obtener datos del día anterior pero... si te fijas en la imagen adjunta, hay una diferencia de fechas de más de 11 días entre ambas fechas, por tanto, difícilmente obtendrías los datos de la fecha del día anterior.

Ahora bien, si lo que deseas lograr es que se obtenga datos del día de hoy y, en caso contrario, se obtengan los datos de la fecha más próxima, este sería la mejor opción:

```
$sql = "SELECT z.nombreZona, cpp.precioMinimo, cpp.precioMaximo, (cpp.precioMinimo + 
    cpp.precioMaximo)/2 AS promedio FROM cargaPrecioPapas cpp INNER JOIN zonas z ON cpp.fkZona 
    = z.idZona WHERE fechaCargaPrecio = (SELECT MAX(fechaCargaPrecio) FROM cargaPrecioPapas)"; 
        
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tem = $row;
        $json = json_encode($tem);
    }
} else {
    // Debe incluirse un mensaje de que no hay registros
}
echo $json;
$conn->close();
```

Lo que hacemos es utilizar una sola sentencia SQL en la que se selecciona la fecha más reciente de transacción, a través de la cláusula {WHERE}, en el que se especifica entre paréntesis que, primero, se selecciona la fecha más reciente encontrada en la tabla (que puede ser la fecha de hoy o puede ser otra fecha reciente como ayer, anteayer, etc) y, luego, se busca dentro de la misma tabla cuales son los registros que coincidan con esa misma fecha.

Si la fecha más reciente obtenida en la cláusula {WHERE} es la fecha de hoy, entonces obtendras los datos de esa misma fecha por una cuestión de coincidencia. En cambio, si la fecha más reciente obtenida en esa misma cláusula {WHERE} es el 21/11/2020 (como está en tu imagen), mostrará los datos de la última fecha más reciente al día de hoy, sin necesidad de preocuparte en hacer dos consultas SQL.